# The Project name in code igniter coming twice automatically

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am facing an issue. whenever i click on a link in my project it show the Project base url twice.

example:

```
http://localhost/shopsy/shopsy/css/default/front/bootstrap.css
```

the project name comes twice in all the link.
i don't have any .htaccess file. and base_url is correctly set:

```
http://localhost/shopsy
```

please help

Comment: Check your base_url

Comment: thanks for your reply. but i checked base url it is correct i think

Comment: Is your base url on config.php `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/shopsy/';`

Comment: Also when you load your css `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('css/default/front/bootstrap.css');?>">`

Comment: Make sure the css is out side of the application folder

Comment: share your css link

Comment: if i go to localhost/project_name. it autmoatically goes to http://localhost/shopsy/shopsy/

Comment: you may done something in .htaccess file or base_url